# Iframe adjastable height of the content (in wordpress)

Tags: javascript, wordpress, iframe, iframe-resizer

I want to insert some theme demo on my site for my clients to see.
But i can't get the iframe height to be as the content height.
A workaround could be to set the iframe height as the browser height less the header/menù of my site. But i don't know how to realize it.

Answer (score 0):

try to use onload event on iframe

```js
fucntion resizeme(elem){
  $(elem).width($(elem.contentWindow.document).width())
    $(elem).height($(elem.contentWindow.document).height())
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<iframe src="/" onload="resizeme(this)" ></iframe>
```

Comment: I'm getting an iframe of 150px of height that i believe is the default height that wordpress use. The width is 100% as i set it.

Comment: I ended up making an iframe of  width 100% and height 75% and making a castom header in the page with 25% height. For now it's ok, I tryed your solution in a simple html page but i get an iframe of 304x154